# Não consigo instanciar classe com parâmetros compilando com aot

Tags: angular, typescript

**Versões.**

```
TUDO ATUALIZADO NA DATA DE HOJE (2017-08-23)
@angular/cli: 1.3.1
node: 8.3.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.5
@angular/common: 4.3.5
@angular/compiler: 4.3.5
@angular/core: 4.3.5
@angular/forms: 4.3.5
@angular/http: 4.3.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.5
@angular/router: 4.3.5
@angular/cli: 1.3.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.5
@angular/language-service: 4.3.5
```

Método 1 COM parâmetros - Compila **COM** ERRO usando

```
ng build --prod ( with aot )
```

e **SEM** ERRO quando compila usando

```
ng build --prod --aot=false (sem aot)
```

**no service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MvsTest {
    public Test: string = "";
    constructor(param: string) { 
        this.Test = param; 
    }
}
```

**no outro service**

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {
    public test1 = new MvsTest ('New1');
    public test2 = new MvsTest ('New2');
    constructor() { }
}
```

Método 2 SEM parâmetro- Compila **SEM** ERRO usando `ng build --prod` ( with aot ) e **SEM** ERRO quando compila usando `ng build --prod --aot=false` (sem aot)

**no service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MvsTest {
    public Test: string = "";
    constructor() { }
}
```

**no outro service**

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {
    public test1 = new MvsTest ();
    public test2 = new MvsTest ();
    constructor() {
        this.test1.Test= 'New1';
        this.test2.Test= 'New2';
    }
}
```

**log do erro.**

```
ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for MvsTest in C:/DEVELOPER/_SHARED/mvs-test/mvs-test.service.ts: (?).
    ERROR in ./src/main.ts..... etc...etc...etc... 
    ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for MvsTest in C:/DEVELOPER/src/app/_SHARED/mvs-test/mvs-test.service.ts: (?).
    ERROR in ./src/main.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\DEVELOPER\src'
    resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\DEVELOPER\src'
      using description file: C:\DEVELOPER\package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      after using description file: C:\DEVELOPER\package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: C:\DEVELOPER\package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory)
          no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            C:\DEVELOPER\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
          .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            C:\DEVELOPER\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
          .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            C:\DEVELOPER\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
          as directory
            C:\DEVELOPER\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
    [C:\DEVELOPER\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory]
    [C:\DEVELOPER\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts]
    [C:\DEVELOPER\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.js]
    [C:\DEVELOPER\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory]
     @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
     @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

**Funcionalidade desejada.**

Eu preciso instanciar a classe com parâmetros pois é mais trabalhoso ter que instanciar sem o parâmetro e depois setar o parâmetro. Quando criamos muitas classes herdadas o código dobra de tamanho caso tenha que criar e depois setar. Serão muitas instâncias e desejo o código muito limpo.
Eu quero compilar com aot.

Eu sei que posso criar e setar a propriedade depois mas realmente gostaria de uma solução onde possa instanciar a classe já com o parâmetro.

Mas... isto não resolve o que realmente preciso porém existe provisoriamente como eu criar algo como este exemplo hipotético?:

```
public test1 = new MvsTest().Test = 'Test1';  // **(hypothetical example)**
```

Muito obrigado

Comment: Sugiro abrir uma issue no repo oficial do angular. Tive problema com AOT também e fui abrir issue la.

Comment: Ok, obrigado Giovane